Max number of queries in a Neo4J Transaction
We seem to be intermittently getting the following exception:
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Cannot run more queries in this transaction, it has either experienced an fatal error or was explicitly terminated; Error code 'N/A'; nested exception is org.neo4j.driver.exceptions.ClientException: Cannot run more queries in this transaction, it has either experienced an fatal error or was explicitly terminated

We've solved this in the past by simply batching things up, however now it's happening again. We're going to further reduce the batch sizing as a temporary fix, however we'd like to put something more dynamic and permanent in.
Is there any documentation anywhere as to the allowed number of queries in a transaction? All I can find from Neo4J themselves is that you can run 1,000 transactions concurrently, but no data on how many queries each of those transactions can make before being terminated. Is this information out there anywhere? Has anyone done any testing themselves to try to determine this number?

As the error message states, the transaction "has either experienced an fatal error or was explicitly terminated". I assume you did not deliberately terminate the transaction, so there was some other exception that ultimately caused the InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException.
The full stack trace for the InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException should show what the other exception was. You have to fix (or work around) that other exception.
